# Multi Subdomain Website using Node?

Tags: node.js

I would love to get advice on my current project structure idea. I have been searching regarding node.js multi domain packages but i am not sure if they will suit. I also would like to have a easy to manage apps eg. if i want to modify specific app, i have a feeling a single app will get really full and confusing to manage code wise? Basically i am building a website that will have:

- Landing Page - www.maindomain.com
- User Dashboard - members.maindomain.com
- Admin Dashboard - admin.maindomain.com

Now each subdomain app can communicate to each other if they have the credidentials etc.

- Would it be correct to create separate 3 Apps to handle each of the sites?
- Is there any security concerns having this kind of 3 app setup?
- Can account creation occur upon paypal payment?

Ideal flow would be User visits website on landing page and selects a paid package which in turn would direct to paypal. Upon payment user would be returned to website with account creation form, and said Package(order) would become an option on user dashboard. 
Admin can pretty much view everything via admin dashboard pretty standard, setup promos etc.

Thanks for your help and advice.

Comment: This is only one domain.

Comment: You can make namespaces with NodeJS so you don't need to have 3 several server files. You can find more information at the Socket.IO documentation: http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces

Comment: You can also take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/subdomain if you use Express

Comment: @C0dekid Basically this would be on one server then i guess right and using a reverse proxy?

Comment: @Fka I have looked at it but i thought perhaps the whole project might get out of hand so many directories and such. That being said i have never prepared a node.js app on production.